# Is there a "uniqueID" type property for address book contacts?

Tags: objective-c, ios, addressbook, uniqueidentifier, abaddressbook

I'm making a game involving the user's contacts, but need a way to uniquely identify each contact. This is because the user can easily change the name, phone number, or other property of a given contact. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ABRecordGetRecordID()` to get the unique ID of a record. It returns an `ABRecordID` which is a typedef for `int32_t`.

Comment: Is an `ABRecord` a person or a property of a person. For example, say I have a person in my address book called "John Smith", would an `ABRecord` object represent "John Smith" and all his properties or just a single property, for example his phone number?

Comment: A `ABRecord` represents a person, so if you change the name of the person, it'll still be represented by the same record.

Comment: I'm a little confused: what's the difference between `ABRecord` and `ABPerson`?

Comment: @qegal From the documentation: "Person records are represented by instances of the ABRecordRef opaque type, whose record type is kABPersonType."

Comment: It turns out that ABRecord is not strictly limited to people (it can also contain groups and properties), so I ended up identifying contacts by the date when they were created, but you pointed me in the right direction, so I'll accept.

Comment: @qegal Yes, it's not limited to people only. Imagine `ABRecord` to be the superclass of `ABPerson`, you can use the `ABRecordGetRecordID()` function on a `ABPerson` to get its unique id (which is what you want)

Comment: ABRecordGetRecordID() is not unique, it changes when synced to iCloud or so

Comment: @JustSid This is unique, but not consistent, so one can't use it to keep references (which is what someone really wants to do with uniqueID). Anyway, you can edit your answer and I can take my vote back

Comment: @aqavi_paracha Yeah, not going to change a factual answer to get rid of a downvote. The unique ID is unique. The question was about unique IDs. My answer points out how to obtain a unique ID. Now what? Just because your idea of unique ID includes that it should be consistent throughout a nuclear apocalypse and the rapture doesn't mean that everyone thinks that's the meaning.

Comment: @JustSid By "edit" I mean to add a space or any character so that I'm able to remove my vote.

Answer (score 2):

ABRecordGetRecordID() is the API that you can use. However, apple documentation does states some noteworthy points about the ABRecordID returned by this API.

> Every record in the Address Book database has a unique record identifier. This identifier always refers to the same record, unless that record is deleted or the data is reset. Record identifiers can be safely passed between threads. They are not guaranteed to remain the same across devices.

The suggested method as per apple guidelines is

> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID for the record.

In my app, I am also checking for creation date of the contact since the name against the ABRecordID could have been changed by the user. Creation date of a contact **DOES NOT** change upon device reset.

[Though I have pasted most of the content here, its always advised to read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html)